# how can i make this script reset if an incorrect password is used?

Tags: python

```
import getpass
 
p = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is the code you were given?? ')
 
if p.lower() == 'breakout':
    print('Welcome..!!!')
else:
  print('The answer entered by you is incorrect..!!!')
```

I tried a few things, all of them gave errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512980/resetting-password-python-program

Answer (score 1):

Reset?. You mean you need to ask again if password is wrong?..if so Use `while True` until password is `Correct`

```
import getpass

while 1:
    
     
    p = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is the code you were given?? ')
     
    if p.lower() == 'breakout':
        print('Welcome..!!!')
        break
    else:
      print('The answer entered by you is incorrect..!!!')
```

output #

```
What is the code you were given?? ok
The answer entered by you is incorrect..!!!

What is the code you were given?? breakout
Welcome..!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
import getpass

p = ""
while p.lower() != "breakout": 
    p = getpass.getpass(prompt="What is the code you were given?? ")
else:
    print("Welcome..!!!")
```